# Fetch documents using get and index in firebase realtime database

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I want to fetch all orders based on the value of date variable.

Here's the function I am using to fetch:

```
Future<void> fetchAllOrders() async {
    var now = DateTime.now();
    var today = now.day.toString()+now.month.toString()+now.year.toString();
    print('Todays time is ' + today.toString()); 
    var filterString ='orderBy="date"&equalTo="$today"';
    final url =     'https://tm-9120.firebaseio.com/ordersdev.json?auth=$authToken&$filterString';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    final data = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    print(data); 
}
```

Here's the structure of my realtime database table:

ordersdev -> userId -> order object containing date variable

[image]

The function returns null. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can't filter on a nested list. You would need to change the path `https://tm-9120.firebaseio.com/ordersdev.json` to semething like this `https://tm-9120.firebaseio.com/ordersdev/firstListUID.json` to go to one of the nested elements and then you can filter to the `date`.

The filter restriction to the one level is very good explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27208492/5519300). It doesn't matter if you use the REST API or SDK (the restriction is the same)

Comment: Fetching the whole list from DB and filtering on client side will be very slow as the list grows. Ain't any other way of doing this server side?

Comment: The other way to do that would be to change your data model to allow the query, as I described in the linked answer.

Comment: I never wrote that you should download the whole list. Just mentioned that it's not possible to filter on nested data. The best solution would be to restructure your database structure.